# UITableView reloading data using NSTimer while scrolling table

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, reloading

I have a simple `UITableView` containing a few rows. Every row contain a countdown timer represented by `UITextLabel`. When row is selected, countdown starts. Countdown fire date is set by `localNotification`. Time to fire date is displayed in `UITextLabel`.

Refreshing table starts in `viewWillApper` method with the line below:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(refreshTable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

`refreshTable` method contain one line:

```
[tableView reloadData]
```

Everything is working as expected, but when I start to scroll the `tableView` (without releasing  the finger) countdown timer is not updated.

I've set up a log inside `refreshTable` method to see whether this method is called when I scroll the table. The result was negative. Somehow `refreshTable` method is not called when I scroll `tableView`.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this issue?

I've checked default Clock App (by apple). In the first tab (world clock) is represented by table view. Inside every row there is a clock with red hand. While scrolling the table the hand is updating which means that updating table view while scrolling is possible...somehow

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You see, the UITableView class has a UIScrollView inside it. You can use `UIScrollViewDelegate` to force reload the page. Here's the doc: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html). Look at `– scrollViewDidScroll:`

Iterate over the Table's subviews until you find the Scroll. If you post some code perhaps I could help more

Comment: scrollViewDidScroll is called only when I scroll the table. When I  stop scrolling (but without releasing scrolling) this method is not called and countdown timers are not updating.

Comment: Ok, i found a solution:  `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];`

Comment: Lvan can you send the  fully code with NSTimer Object.